# days between date calculation

Tags: python, date, calendar, date-arithmetic

I am making a package of functions that gets different values from dates as you can see from the code below. It works, but it sometimes returns values that are off by a small amount.

The code:

```
    #CALENDAR TOOLS FUNCTIONS
    #CALENDAR INDEXING USES FORMAT: MMM DD, YYYY

    #example: "Aug 17, 1998"

    month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']                
    monthLength = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

    def getMonth(date):
        return date[0:3]

    def getDay(date):
        return int(date[4:6])

    def getYear(date):
        return int(date[8:12])

    def years(a, b):
        a = getYear(a)
        b = getYear(b)
        if a > b:
            return a - b - 1
        else:
            return b - a - 1

    def days(a, b):

        #switches years if start date is past end date
        if (getYear(a) > getYear(b) or
            getYear(a) == getYear(b) and month.index(getMonth(a)) >         month.index(getMonth(b)) or
            getYear(a) == getYear(b) and month.index(getMonth(a)) == month.index(getMonth(b)) and getDay(a) > getDay(b)):
            a, b = b, a

        dayA = getDay(a)
        monthA = getMonth(a)
        yearA = getYear(a)

        dayB = getDay(b)
        monthB = getMonth(b)
        yearB = getYear(b)

        remDays = monthLength[month.index(monthA)] - dayA + 1
        for i in range(month.index(monthA), 11):
            remDays += monthLength[i]

        prevDays = dayB
        for i in range(0, month.index(monthB)):
            prevDays += monthLength[i]

        yearDays = round(years(a, b) * 365.24218967, 0)
        totalDays = yearDays + remDays + prevDays
        return totalDays
```

When i use the days function with some dates it gets right on some but off a bit on others I will give an example if i input:

```
days("Jan 01, 2013", "Dec 31, 2015")
```

for the days I get the correct answer of 1095 days
I am getting if it is correct or not from http://www.timeanddate.com/date/duration.html

but when i input:

```
days("Jan 01, 1908", "Sep 07, 2000")
```

for the days this time i get 33852 days
from the timeanddate.com website i get 33,791 a huge difference and i do not get why

Comment: I know I can use built in, but I am doing this for fun and I am curious about why my results are varying

Comment: You don't seem to be taking care of leap years. But that only accounts for 23 missing days. You're missing 61.

Comment: The "fun" part working correctly will have to reach the well tested by millions of programers "datetime" module - and there are idopsyncrazies. I don't think you will get far trying to calculate dates using a floating point value for the year like that, . Good luck with that ,while I see no provision even for leap years  (that is to pick Feb the 29th date, even though you get the "average year lenght" correctly)

Comment: Dates are not an exact science, they are a bureaucracy, with a list of special cases as long as your leg. Some countries have missed weeks on their calendar when they switched from Gregorian to Julian. I'd say your approximation is close enough.

Comment: I still don't get what the exact problem is. It's clearly not just leap years.

Comment: I made a leap year func that returns if a leap year or not. I got the answer down to 33830, 22 down from before dang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing it for fun I won't change much what you did. What you are missing (as some people pointed out) is the leap year calculation. Also a couple of details:

1) The first prevDays loop should go from month.index(monthA) + 1 to 12. Remember than range() includes the first arg but excludes the second one, as in: [arg1, arg2).

2) You have an extra + 1 on remDays. It shouldn't be there.

3) You are missing the leap year calculation. You can calculate leap years as

```
def is_leap_year(year):
    return (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or year % 400 == 0
```

so, on your month loops I'd add:

```
for i in range(month.index(monthA) + 1, 12):
    remDays += monthLength[i] + (1 if i == 1 and is_leap_year(yearA) else 0)
```

and

```
for i in range(0, month.index(monthB)):
    prevDays += monthLength[i] + (1 if i == 1 and is_leap_year(yearB) else 0)
```

Lastly, you need to add 366 days on leap years instead of 365. So, continuing your loop-style, this would be the year calculation:

```
yearDays = 0
for year in range(yearA + 1, yearB):
    yearDays += 366 if is_leap_year(year) else 365
```

Note that this last piece would go instead of your round(..) stuff.

Comment: I did try an implementation of proper leap years, but this is a far better way of doing this. What i find weird is that I was looking at a different date to date calculator and it gave 33853 for my problem case. This same result as with this solution and 1 off from my original solution. However the timeanddate website had 33791 which leads the question which one do I go off of?

Comment: OK, Now I feel stupid, my original result was 1 off which is good but 33853 is the correct answer not 33791 I went back to the timeanddate website and realized I accidentally put july instead of september. Sorry to waste your time. Your leap year implementation is good though thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your handling of leap years is broken. There are exact rules for leap years, and if you approximate them using your logic (`years(a, b) * 365.24218967`) you get erroneous results.

Convert your input to a `datetime.date()` object and use the difference of those.

```
def days_diff(a, b):
    dta = datetime.date(getYear(a), getMonth(a), getDay(a))
    dtb = datetime.date(getYear(b), getMonth(b), getDay(b))
    return (dta - dtb).days
```

**Edit:** Reading your comment that you're doing this for fun and not wanting to use Python's builtin time functions. Then, as Jayanth also commented, take proper care of leap years. Look up the rules when they happen and implement them.

Comment: If you're going to use datetime, then there's no point of this anyway. OP says he is trying to do it from scratch.

Comment: If you're going to `datetime` objects, you might as well just subtract them directly and get a `timedelta` object. But OP stated he wanted to do this manually.

Comment: Didn't know you could subtract ``datetime`` objects directly. Neat. Updated my answer to use that (and made it a community wiki). Thanks.

Comment: +1 because doing date time yourself, even as a fun exercise, is really just an exercise in frustration.